# Kendo ListBox - Drag/Drop does not work if have multi-select enabled

Tags: kendo-ui, listbox, telerik

It doesn't seem like the new ListBox widget can be configured for both Drag/Drop and multi-selection in the same instance.  I see that the "Events" demo on the Telerik site has both of these properties set, but cannot actually drag any entries between the 2 ListBoxes.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/events

Is this a bug?  Or can only one of these functions be enabled for a specific ListBox instance?

Comment: Single item drag and drop works. But I cannot drag and drop multiple items at once.

Answer (score 0):

Only one item can be dragged at a time between two listboxes.
Howewer, you can use transferTo and transferFrom functionalities to pass your selection between lists.

Comment: I see how all of the various functionalities work when configured individually.  I have tested the drag/drop and multiple selection separately, and they work perfectly.  

However, the demo referenced in the OP has both of these functionalities enabled in both listboxes.  The multiple selection works fine and can transfer selections between the 2 listboxes using the transfer buttons.  But, cannot drag anything between the listboxes, not even a single selection.

Comment: Looking at the code of that demo, there are events wired up for "drag" and "drop", but these never fire.  The drag mouse action just draws a highlighted box that selects the items touched by that box when the mouse is released.

Comment: I have just checked your demo example - it works fine for single drag and drop.

Comment: Hmm..Interesting. I tried it with Edge explorer (Win 10) and it works.  But in Chrome and Firefox on the same computer, it is not working.  The drag action is just creating a blue box.

But on a different Win 10 laptop, it works in Edge and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Both computers are running the same version of Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Just tested on IE and problem occured. Have just found something on a Telerik forum that corresponds with our problem: "Scnearios that involve drag and drop with multiple selection are not supported because the drag and drop functionality interferes with the multiselection.
Please use single selection to avoid any further issues." Looks like only option is to to use single mode.

Comment: If it would work consistently across all browsers to drag one item, even with multi-selection enabled, that would be fine.  I'll have to discuss with my team about what is the most important feature for our application.   Thanks for helping out.